# How to use filter Odata Expression in Docs.microsoft Focus Mode

Tags: c#, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-fluent-api, microsoft-documentation

I'm trying to get the list of all resources based on its type using Azure API.

I can able to achieve this using Azure Fluent SDK

```
var resource = resouceManagementClient.Resources.ListAsync(new ODataQuery<GenericResourceFilterInner>(x => x.ResourceType == "microsoft.insights/alertrules")).Result;
```

However, I couldn't able to get this work with the Focus mode in the [Microsoft doc site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list).

My Actal request is going like below

> GET
>   /subscriptions//resources?$filter=resourceType%20eq%20'microsoft.insights%2Falertrules'&api-version=2017-05-10

I tried the same within the focused editor

[image]

> But still, this results in all resources, not only the type
>   `microsoft.insights/alertrules`

What I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to my test screenshot, it works fine,`resourceType eq 'Microsoft.Insights/alertRules'`.

[image]

**Note**: After passing the parameter, click the "**+**" symbol.

[image]